# How to change the way theorems are displayed?

Tags: formatting, theorems, amsthm

I am in the process of writing a large document containing some theorems, lemma, and propositions. Currently, I am using packages `amsmath` and `amsthm`. I defined my own environment for theorems by adding

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm} {Theorem}[chapter]
```

to the preamble. However, I am not quite satisfied with the looks. So is there a possibility to change the way this would be displayed? I would like to have the word "Theorem" appear in *small caps*. Furthermore, I would like a line break after the theorem's title.

What is the best way to do this? Are there nice packages for this purpose (prefereably without too much fiddling)?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`amsthm` provides the `\newtheoremstyle` command for defining new theorem styles. It is described in the [`amsthm` documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf). To have a style that is the same as `plain` except for the header font, you can use

```
\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle} % name
    {\topsep}                    % Space above
    {\topsep}                    % Space below
    {\itshape}                   % Body font
    {}                           % Indent amount
    {\scshape}                   % Theorem head font
    {.}                          % Punctuation after theorem head
    {.5em}                       % Space after theorem head
    {}  % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
```

The [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package provides even more flexibility (as Charles hinted).

Comment: Thanks, this look nice, too. I am a bit embarrassed that I missed it while skimming the documentations...

Comment: Is it possible to base a new style on an existing style, and to change only some of the parameters?

Comment: @Alexey: AFAIK, not with `amsthm`. Possibly with `thmtools` or `ntheorem`. Best to ask a new question (search first if it has already been asked).

Comment: @Caramdir How did you figure out these parameters?

Answer (score 18):

You may also use the [`thmtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) package which offers a key-value-interface to define new theorem styles and theorems. (The package acts as a frontend to the `amsthm` and `ntheorem` packages, and one of these should be loaded before `thmtools`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\scshape,postheadspace=\newline]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Some text.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. I am currently using Caramdir's approach, though.

Comment: This is a much better syntax.  In fact, it starts to look like Context's `\defineenumeration`...

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
\usepackage[amsthm]{ntheorem}
\newcommand{\theoremheaderfont}{\scshape}
```

(using `ntheorem` in place of `amsthm`).

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting. In your experience, are there any side effects I should be aware of (changed margins, changed spacing etc.)?

Comment: @Bran: The amsthm option to ntheorem is supposed to give amsthm-like definitions.  I couldn't say how good an approximation they are, since I never used amsthm.