# Theorems and Definitions as quotes

Tags: spacing, environments, theorems, rules

Most standard styles highlight theorems and definitions using italics. Now this is something I really would like to avoid in my thesis (and generally). Unfortunately, if I just remove this "feature", I am left with the problem that it isn't obvious anymore where a theorem ends and the normal body text continues. I am wondering whether there is a not-too-complicated way to make theorem environments visually like quote environments, i. e. greater horizontal offset. What should I do?

An additional question in case this is too easy: What if I don't just want a greater horizontal offset, but also a vertical line on the level of the normal offset going all the way down until the end of the theorem?

Comment: Perhaps the answers to this question: [How to change the way theorems are displayed?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/how-to-change-the-way-theorems-are-displayed) will be helpful.

Comment: welcome darij grinberg..........................................................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question, you can define a new environment using the `quote` environment and some therem-like structure from, for example, the [amsthm](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package; for the second question, the `leftbar` environment from the [framed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed) package can be useful. A little example that you can use as starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{Qtheorem}[1][]
  {\quote\begin{theo}[#1]}
  {\end{theo}\endquote}
\newenvironment{Btheorem}[1][]
  {\begin{theo}[#1]\begin{leftbar}}
  {\end{leftbar}\end{theo}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{Qtheorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{Qtheorem}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{Btheorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{Btheorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: or switch to the `ntheorem` package, which can do even wilder markings

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, thanks a lot, but I'm getting errors like these: http://pastebin.com/PKXP8ekw Could you comment on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @darij grinberg: you are using `\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}` but I defined `theo` instead of `theorem`, so simply change `\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}` to `\newtheorem{lemma}[theo]{Lemma}`

Comment: This doesn't change anything, I fear.

Comment: @darij grinberg: then, please post a *minimal* and *complete* version of your code, so that I can see where the problem is.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LsR2TGqi Minimal maybe not (there are packages I don't like removing, as I don't know what they do), but complete.

Comment: @darij grinberg: I took your code and made the change I suggested in my previous comment, and the document compiled OK in my system. Try again changing in the code you just posted changing `\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}` to `\newtheorem{lemma}[theo]{Lemma}` and see if that helps. If not then perhaps you are using some outdated package(s)?

Comment: Ah, I was an idiot. I changed only the first newtheorem, but there were more of it further below. Thank you!