# Theorem in quote environment

Tags: environments, theorems

I would like to use a theorem-like environment inside a quote environment (or with the same spacing as a quote environment).

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14453/28115) the following solution is presented:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{Qtheorem}[1][]
  {\quote\begin{theo}[#1]}
  {\end{theo}\endquote}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{Qtheorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{Qtheorem}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

However, it produces extra/unwanted space at the top of the environment:

[image]

Can this be fixed directly?

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67251/4427 help?

Comment: @egreg It does, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%
{0pt}%space above
{0pt}%space below
{}% body font
{}% paragraph indent amount
{\bfseries}% head font
{.}% punctuation after head
{.5em}% space after head
{}% headspec

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{Qtheorem}[1][]
  {\quote\begin{theo}[#1]}
  {\end{theo}\endquote}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{Qtheorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{Qtheorem}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like I shouldn't, but for some reason I get the same amount of space with your example as in the picture in the question.