# amsthm: what are the newtheoremstyle parameters for the default styles?

Tags: theorems, amsthm

The package `amsthm` contains the predefined theorem styles `plain`, `definition` and `remark` which you can employ using `\theoremstyle` before your `\newtheorem`.

You can also create new theorem styles like this:
`\newtheoremstyle{NAME}{ABOVESPACE}{BELOWSPACE}{BODYFONT}{INDENT}{HEADFONT}{HEADPUNCT}{HEADSPACE}{CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC}`. I.e. you have to set all properties of your new style at once.

But I mostly like them as they are, I only want to change like 1 parameter. Therefore I'd like to know the `\newtheoremstyle` parameters which produce the predefined styles, so I can copy them and only change what I want. I would expect that information to be in the documentation of the package, but it isn't. Does anyone know what they are?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The style "plain" should be equivalent to

```
\newtheoremstyle{plain}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
```

The style "definition" is the same except for the body font, which is `\normalfont`; in "remark" the spaces above and below are `0.5\topsep`, the head font is `\itshape` and the body font is `\normalfont`.

Comment: @egreg: should be? did you guess it by the looks, or did you find that information somewhere? here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/how-to-change-the-way-theorems-are-displayed it looks a bit different. is a space the same as .5em and is \noindent the same as leaving it blank?

Comment: @peter: `\noindent` is wrong, and actually the space between the header and the text is `5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt`. Thanks for remarking.

Comment: @egreg: what's the effect of +1-1? shouldnt this be the same as dropping it?

Comment: @peter: no; this means that the space may be stretched up to 6pt or shrinked up to 4pt. It's a "rubber length" as it's called in Lamport's manual.

Comment: @egreg, @peter -- the `plus` in a rubber length may actually be stretched to more than the stated value, though the `minus` is the absolute limit.  stretch is applied proportionally to all horizontal spaces in a paragraph or vertical spaces on a page; if a `fil` is present, it overwhelms anything else, but if there is no other stretch in the scope of what's being stretched, the `1pt' would expand to fill the entire amount needed to justify or make a page flush bottom.

Comment: @barbara: You're right, but when the stretch is more than the stated value, the badness of the box increases. Stated in a different way: the space may be stretched *optimally* up to 6pt, but if really necessary TeX will stretch it more, possibly producing an underfull box.

Comment: First, I just want to thank egreg for his comment. Saved me a lot of time! I have a question though - when I try to put "\underline" as the Thm head font, it doesn't change anything. Does anyone know if there's a special command for an underlined font? I'm using "\scshape" as a nice-looking alternative for now.

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton `\underline` is not a font changing command. And underlining is frowned upon in typographic circles.

Comment: Is there no way to "inherit" a new style from an existing one, overriding only some parameters?

Comment: @Alexey I don't think there's a very good way, the actual numbers are lost after the command is executed as they're packed into the `\th@⟨style name⟩`  macro for efficiency reason (so e.g. `\th@customstyle` may be defined to be `\itshape \let \thm@indent \noindent \thm@headsep 5pt␣plus␣1pt␣minus␣1pt\relax \thm@preskip 8.0pt␣plus␣2.0pt␣minus␣4.0pt\thm@postskip 8.0pt␣plus␣2.0pt␣minus␣4.0pt\relax \thm@headfont {\bfseries }\thm@headpunct {.}`), and it isn't exactly trivial to parse out the values from that. The built-in styles are special cased (e.g. `\th@plain` = `\itshape`) so even harder.

Comment: @egreg I think the "5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt" should actually be ".5em"; I ran an example on my local TeX installation and found that the spacing given by your answer is too small (at least in the example that I tried).

Comment: @xFioraMstr18 No, the package has `\thm@headsep=5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt`