# Subnumerating Definitions

Tags: amsmath, enumerate, appendices

Since this is my first question I hope that the Example is short and enough to reproduce my problem. I am creating an Appendix and I want to "subnumerate" Definitions. Actual it looks like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\section{Anhang}
\subsection{Mathematischer Anhang}
\subsubsection*{Definitionen}
\begin{definition}[Subgradienten und -differentiale]
Sei $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ eine konvexe (aber nicht zwingend differenzierbare) Funktion, dann ist der Vektor $s\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ der Subgradient von $f$ an der Stelle $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $, wenn gilt:
\begin{align*}
f(y) \geq f(x) + s^T(y-x)
\end{align*}
Die Menge aller Subgradienten einer konvexen Funktion $f$ an der Stelle $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ wird Subdifferential $\partial f(x)$ genannt. \\
Bei einer konvexen und differenzierbaren Funktion f ist der Subgradient gleich dem Gradienten $\partial f(x)=\nabla f(x)$.
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My aim is to subnumerate the last sentence in Definition 1. So the Output should be:

**Definition 1** text

**Definition 1.1** *Bei einer konvexen ..*

Note that the numeration doesnt depend on a specific chapter in my text. So its not my goal to start a new numeration with each chapter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! So the "sub-number" should reset with each definition? That would basically only involve a counter defined like `\newcounter{subdefinition}[definition]` and an environment that uses `\thesubdefinition`.

Comment: Thanks  ! But it doesnt work. I get a "0" instead of it. But you are Right the "sub-number" should reset with each new definition

Comment: Are you sure that you increment the counter within the environment you defined for the subdefinition? A `\refstepcounter{subdefinition}` will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply define a new counter and use that in a new environment which also allows you to omit that `\\`.

[image: sub definition]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\newcounter{subdefinition}[definition]
\renewcommand{\thesubdefinition}{\thedefinition.\arabic{subdefinition}}
\newenvironment{subdefinition}{
        \refstepcounter{subdefinition}
        \par\noindent
        \textbf{\upshape Definition \thesubdefinition}%
}{}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\section{Anhang}
\subsection{Mathematischer Anhang}
\subsubsection*{Definitionen}
\begin{definition}[Subgradienten und -differentiale]
Sei $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ eine konvexe (aber nicht zwingend differenzierbare) Funktion, dann ist der Vektor $s\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ der 
Subgradient von $f$ an der Stelle $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $, wenn gilt:
\begin{align*}
f(y) \geq f(x) + s^T(y-x)
\end{align*}
Die Menge aller Subgradienten einer konvexen Funktion $f$ an der Stelle $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ wird Subdifferential $\partial f(x)$ genannt.
\begin{subdefinition}
Bei einer konvexen und differenzierbaren Funktion f ist der Subgradient gleich dem Gradienten $\partial f(x)=\nabla f(x)$.
\end{subdefinition}
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had a mistake. Awesome, thanks ! But I cant vote up since I have less then 15 reps

Answer (score 0):

Define a new theorem style (for removing the surrounding vertical space) and a subordinate theorem-like environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17555/4427
\newtheoremstyle{subdefinition}
  {0pt}       % ABOVESPACE
  {0pt}       % BELOWSPACE
  {\upshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\theoremstyle{subdefinition}
\newtheorem{subdefinition}{Definition}[definition]

\begin{document}

\appendix
\section{Anhang}
\subsection{Mathematischer Anhang}
\subsubsection*{Definitionen}

\begin{definition}[Subgradienten und -differentiale]
Sei $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ eine konvexe 
(aber nicht zwingend differenzierbare) Funktion, dann ist der 
Vektor $s\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ der Subgradient von $f$ an der Stelle 
$x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $, wenn gilt:
\begin{equation*}
f(y) \geq f(x) + s^T(y-x)
\end{equation*}
Die Menge aller Subgradienten einer konvexen Funktion $f$ an der 
Stelle $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ wird Subdifferential $\partial f(x)$ genannt.
\begin{subdefinition}
Bei einer konvexen und differenzierbaren Funktion f ist der Subgradient 
gleich dem Gradienten $\partial f(x)=\nabla f(x)$.
\end{subdefinition}
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
Abc def ghi
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]