# Missing vertical space around a theorem environment when using enumitem

Tags: spacing, koma-script, theorems, enumitem

When a theorem environment (defined via `amsthm`) is used inside of an `enumerate` environment, then some vertical space around the theorem environment seems to be missing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    Here is text.

    \begin{test}
      Here is a proposition.
    \end{test}

    Here is more text.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This is the output (with `latex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`):

[image: With enumitem.]

This is the expected output, which one gets without `enumitem`:

[image: Without enumitem.]

The same problem occurs with `itemize` and `description` instead of `enumerate`.
How can I get the expected spacing while still using `enumitem`?

Comment: I tried with the class `{article}` and found that there's no problem with it, the problem is inside `{scrartcl}` class.

Comment: added tag `koma-script` since the problem occurs only in that context.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The problem does not only occur with KOMA-Script. Try `article` and add package `parskip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interaction issue of `enumitem` and KOMA-Script is:

- `enumitem` does redefine `trivlist` environment by default. And this redefinition does call `\@listi`, `\@listii`. Something that the original definition of `trivlist` in the LaTeX kernel does not.
- KOMA-Script classes has extra code in `\@listi` etc. for documents (or passages of documents) to avoid addition of `\parskip` and usual `\topsep`. This sets `\topsep` to zero whenever `\parskip` is greater than zero. But inside `enumitem`'s `trivlist` `\parskip` is already greater than zero, when `\@listi` (etc.) is called. So `\topsep` is set to zero.

However `enumitem` does also provide an option `ignoredisplayed` as a workaround for such problems:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}
\usepackage[ignoredisplayed]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    Here is text.

    \begin{test}
      Here is a proposition.
    \end{test}

    Here is more text.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

or you can setup `trivlist` to explicitly set `\topsep`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[trivlist]{topsep=8pt plus 4pt minus 4pt} 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    Here is text.

    \begin{test}
      Here is a proposition.
    \end{test}

    Here is more text.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

a third suggestion would be to patch `enumitem`'s redefinition of `trivlist` to not execute KOMA-Script's extra list code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% Hack to not use KOMA-Script's extra list code inside enumitem's redefinition of trivlist
\xpatchcmd\trivlist{%
  \csname @list\romannumeral\the\@listdepth\endcsname
}{%
  \let\orig@list@extra\@list@extra
  \let\@list@extra\relax
  \csname @list\romannumeral\the\@listdepth\endcsname
  \let\@list@extra\orig@list@extra
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    Here is text.

    \begin{test}
      Here is a proposition.
    \end{test}

    Here is more text.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This is something, `enumitem` or KOMA-Script could do as a workaround to avoid the problem in this context. However, the problem does also occur using a standard class and package `parskip`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    Here is text.

    \begin{test}
      Here is a proposition.
    \end{test}

    Here is more text.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

so it is not related and not restricted to KOMA-Script. Here the second suggestion from above does also work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[trivlist]{topsep=8pt plus 4pt minus 4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    Here is text.

    \begin{test}
      Here is a proposition.
    \end{test}

    Here is more text.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

but the others won't.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is in interaction between `enumitem` and `scrartcl`.

You can solve it by copying the definition of the plain style, but using a different parameter for the above and below separation. The code for the plain style is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17555/4427

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newlength{\defaulttopsep}
\setlength{\defaulttopsep}{\topsep}
\newtheoremstyle{eiplain}
  {\defaulttopsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\defaulttopsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{eiplain}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    Here is text.

    \begin{test}
      Here is a proposition.
    \end{test}

    Here is more text.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions.

---

1. Change [`scrartcl`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrartcl) class to another standard LaTeX class, e.g. [`article`](https://ctan.org/pkg/article), [`book`](https://ctan.org/pkg/book). This will solve your problem. The code and the output are shown below.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}%or book, report, etc.
%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
    \newtheorem{test}{Test}
%
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Here is text.%
            \begin{test}
                \lipsum[1]
            \end{test}
        \item Here is more text.
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{test}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{test}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

2. Place a `\bigskip` right before the theorem, in order to force the right vertical space.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}
%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
    \newtheorem{test}{Test}
%
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Here is text.\bigskip%place here the skip, can be \smallskip, \medskip, \parskip, or a custom \vskip4cm
            \begin{test}
                \lipsum[1]
            \end{test}
        \item Here is more text.
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{test}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{test}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: Output2]