# How to change the headfont of newtheorem environments to match komascript font?

Tags: fonts, koma-script, newtheorem

I'd like to change the theorem environment headfont to match komascript's fonts in chapters and sections. Particularly I'm interested in knowing how to do this using packages like `thmtools`.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction to the theorem}

Introduction of something. Here's the theorem:

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `amsthm`, looking at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17555/4427 where the standard values are listed:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{komaplain}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries\sffamily} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{komaplain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction to the theorem}

Introduction of something. Here's the theorem:

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}[Note]
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `thmtools` you can change the `headfont` as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\sffamily\bfseries]{thm}
\declaretheorem[style=thm]{thm}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction to the theorem}

Introduction of something. Here's the theorem:

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! To make the body text italic do we just add the option `bodyfont=\itshape` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example code with `amsthm` and `thmtools`. Note that `thmtools` also cooperates with `ntheorem`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\declaretheoremstyle[%
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,%
headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
notefont=\sffamily\bfseries, notebraces={(}{)},
headpunct =\,—,
bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape]%
{sf}
\declaretheorem[style=sf, within=chapter, name=Theorem]{theo}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\section{Introduction to the theorem}

Introduction of something. Here's the theorem:

\begin{theo}[using a sans font]
This is a well-known theorem.
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that `headfont` matches the font settings of chapter and section titles in a KOMA-Script document use

`\usekomafont{disposition}`

The initial definition for the `disposition` font element is `\normalcolor\sffamily\bfseries`. But this can be changed using `\setkomafont` or `\addtokomafont`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{remreset}% comment this line, if you use an older TeX-Distribution
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

%\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\usekomafont{disposition}]{thm}
\declaretheorem[style=thm]{thm}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction to the theorem}

Introduction of something. Here's the theorem:

\begin{thm}[Note]
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Additional remark: `thmtools` loads package `remreset` which is obsolete with uptodate TeX distributions. To avoid the resulting warning »The `remreset` package is obsolete: `\@removefromreset` is defined.« KOMA-Script command `\PreventPackageFromLoading{remreset}` is used in the example.