# Adding a superscript to a numbered list

Tags: superscripts

I've defined a theorem-like environment called `ex` for exercises for my students. Some of them are taken from other authors and I'd like to give them credit. In order to do that, I was thinking of marking the exercises with $\star$ or $\dag$ superscripts to the exercise number. I've done so through

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[subsection]

\begin{document}

\begin{ex}\textsuperscript{$\star$} Question
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```

However, the superscript appears at a distance of the number itself and looks odd because of the space inserted after the exercise number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather define a new theorem style which adds the star automatically. This makes it easier to change it e.g. to a `\dag` if you decide so. The default definitions for the style `plain` can be found in the answer to [amsthm: what are the newtheoremstyle parameters for the default styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17551/82917).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[subsection]

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17555/82917
\newtheoremstyle{plain*}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {\itshape}
  {0pt}
  {\bfseries}
  {\textsuperscript{*}.}% <-- this is usually just .
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
  {}    
\theoremstyle{plain*}
\newtheorem{ex*}[ex]{Exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{ex}
Question
\end{ex}

\begin{ex*}
Question
\end{ex*}

\begin{ex}
Question
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But now it's the period after the asterisk the one that looks odd

Comment: @Patricio I agree, but you can exchange them. The seventh argument of `\newtheoremstyle` controls whatever is put after the number. Write whatever you want there.

Comment: As I have several sources, I've tried repeating this with different names and symbols, but only the last definition is used.

Comment: @Patricio `\newtheorem` always uses the last `\theoremstyle`.

Comment: Ok. Do you have any suggestion for differentiating exercices by source?

Comment: You could set up an internal `\newtheorem` which uses some helper macro, and the user environments which define this macro to whatever symbol you want. However, this is beyond the scope of this question as it stands. You might want to ask a new question, but please provide *all* information.

Comment: I just have. In case you care to take a look: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619646/different-superscipts-in-a-list