# Different superscripts in a list

Tags: superscripts

In a previous question from mine (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619635/adding-a-superscript-to-a-numbered-list)) I asked about adding superscripts to numbered lists in order tho acknowledge authorship of some exercises. I accepted campa's suggestion of defining a new theorem style. However, (and this was not part of my original question) as I have several sources, I've tried to replicate the same procedure with different superscripts only to find out that only the most recent theorem style applies.

So my question is How can I add different superscripts to a numbered list? I'd like to be able to obtain something like

1^{\star}

2

3^{\dagger}

4

...

campa's suggestion follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[subsection]

\newtheoremstyle{plain*}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {\itshape}
  {0pt}
  {\bfseries}
  {.\textsuperscript{*}}% <-- this is usually just .
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
  {}    
\theoremstyle{plain*}
\newtheorem{ex*}[ex]{Exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{ex}
Question
\end{ex}

\begin{ex*}
Question
\end{ex*}

\begin{ex}
Question
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```