# \noindent commands ignored

Tags: indentation

Why are the `\noindent` commands ignored in the following code? The only indentation that I want is the paragraph preceding the two corollaries.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}




\begin{document}




We will review bilinear forms and the matrix representations for them. For a reference, one may refer to Applications of Linear Algebra by David C Lay, Judith McDonald, and Steven R Lay.
\vskip0.25in


\noindent \textbf{Corollary 1} \\\vspace{1.25mm}
\noindent {\em $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ are two bases for $V$, and $P \in \mathrm{M}_{n}(F)$ is the transition matrix from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{B}$. If $A$ is the matrix representation of a form on $V$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$,}
\begin{equation*}
A^{\prime} = P^{t}AP
\end{equation*}
{\em is the matrix representation of the same form with respect to $\mathcal{C}$.} \\
\vspace{0.25in}


\noindent \textbf{Corollary 2} \\\vspace{1.25mm}
\noindent {\em If A is the matrix representation for a form on V with respect to a basis for $V$, for any invertible matrix $Q \in {\mathrm{M}}_{n}(F)$,}
\begin{equation*}
A^{\prime} = Q A Q^{t}
\end{equation*}
{\em is the matrix representation of the same form with respect to another basis for V.} \\
\vspace{0.25in}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `A^{\prime}` is more usually input as `A'`

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  Only the first paragraph begins with an indentation.  Why are you saying that `\noindent` is being ignored?  Furthermore, this is not about `tex-core`; it's a LaTeX document, but I'm not sure how to tag it because it's not clear what is wanted.

Comment: @barbara beeton The code for the statement in Corollary 1 begins with `\noindent {\em $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ ... }` That `\noindent` command is being ignored. Same can be said for the `\noindent` command in the code for the statement in Corollary 2.

Comment: When I tested the example on an up-to-date unix system (processing from the command line), everything was flush left (i.e., not indented) except for the opening paragraph. So if the lines following the `\\\vspace_...}` *were* indented for you, something else is going on, and more information is needed.  But the two answers give a more LaTeX-y method for obtaining the result you are looking for.

Comment: This question is relevant: [When to use `\par` and when ``\\``](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664)

Answer (score 1):

`\noindent` should almost never be used in a document, but if it  is used it only does anything at the start of a paragraph.

so

```
\noindent\textbf{Corollary 1}
```

prevents the indentation of "Corollary" (this should be set with a theorem enviroment not a font change)

```
\noindent {\em $\mathcal{B}$ an
```

does nothing as it is mid-paragraph, the space before B is not a paragraph indent; it is a spurious word space added as you have a space (end of line) after `\\\vspace{1.25mm}`

I just added ths although I notice egreg added a similar example

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{break}%
{}{}%           % Note that final punctuation is omitted.
{\itshape}{}%
{\bfseries}{}%
{\newline}{}

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}


\begin{document}




We will review bilinear forms and the matrix representations for
them. For a reference, one may refer to Applications of Linear Algebra
by David C Lay, Judith McDonald, and Steven R Lay.



\begin{cor}
  $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ are two bases for $V$, and
  $P \in \mathrm{M}_{n}(F)$ is the transition matrix from
  $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{B}$. If $A$ is the matrix representation
  of a form on $V$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$,
\begin{equation*}
A' = P^{t}AP
\end{equation*}
is the matrix representation of the same form with respect to $\mathcal{C}$.
\end{cor}


\begin{cor}
  If A is the matrix representation for a form on V with respect to a
  basis for $V$, for any invertible matrix
  $Q \in {\mathrm{M}}_{n}(F)$,
\begin{equation*}
A' = Q A Q^{t}
\end{equation*}
is the matrix representation of the same form with respect to another
basis for V.
\end{cor}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You had stated that `\noindent {\em $\mathcal{B}$ an ...}` is in the middle of a paragraph. I thought the `\\\vspace{1.25mm}` preceding it would have made it into the beginning of a paragraph.

Comment: @user143462 neither `\\ ` nor `\vspace` end a paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like the following?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtheoremstyle{break}
 {0.25in}
 {0.25in}
 {\itshape}
 {0pt}
 {\bfseries\vspace{1.25mm}}
 {\newline}
 {0pt}
 {}

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}

\begin{document}

We will review bilinear forms and the matrix representations for them. 
For a reference, one may refer to Applications of Linear Algebra by 
David C.~Lay, Judith McDonald, and Steven R.~Lay.

\begin{corollary}
$\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ are two bases for $V$, and 
$P \in \mathrm{M}_{n}(F)$ is the transition matrix from 
$\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{B}$. If $A$ is the matrix 
representation of a form on $V$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$,
\begin{equation*}
A' = P^{t}AP
\end{equation*}
is the matrix representation of the same form with respect to $\mathcal{C}$.
\end{corollary}

\begin{corollary}
If $A$ is the matrix representation for a form on $V$ with respect to 
a basis for $V$, for any invertible matrix $Q \in {\mathrm{M}}_{n}(F)$,
\begin{equation*}
A' = Q A Q^{t}
\end{equation*}
is the matrix representation of the same form with respect to another basis for $V$.
\end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is the typesetting that I want. My concern is having the `\newtheoremstyle{break}` in the preamble. I will have similar typesetting with "Definition" and with "Theorem," and I don't know how to adapt this code for that.

Comment: @user143462 `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}` and similarly for theorems. Both after `\theoremstyle{break}`.

Comment: I will try to adapt my code. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have `{0.25in}` twice and `{}` in your `\newtheorem` command?

Comment: @user143462 Isn't that the space above and below you want? For an explanation of the parameters, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17555/4427