# Color of the words (theorem, definition , fact)

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts, tex2lyx

Thank you all. How can I change the `color` of the `word` (e.g., `theorem`) to the `red color` in `lyx` automatically. Also the same thing with the words(`definition, lemma, fact, proof`).

Many thanks
[image]

For example:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass book
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
theorems-ams
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "Times New Roman"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\float_placement h
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize a4paper
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 2.5cm
\topmargin 2.5cm
\rightmargin 2.5cm
\bottommargin 2.5cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Chapter
series
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
\begin_inset Note Note
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout
10.4
\end_layout

\end_inset

 Convergence & Divergence of Series
\end_layout

\begin_layout Definition
Let 
\begin_inset Formula $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$
\end_inset

 a series, we call the sequence 
\begin_inset Formula $\left\{ s_{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty}$
\end_inset

 the partial sums sequence.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Divergence Test
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Notice that for the two series that converged the series term itself was
 zero in the limit.
 This will always be true for convergent series and leads to the following
 theorem.
 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Theorem
\begin_inset Note Note
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Theorem
\end_layout

\end_inset

 If 
\begin_inset Formula $\sum a_{n}$
\end_inset

 converges then 
\begin_inset Formula $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{\mathrm{n}}=0$
\end_inset

.
 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Fact
Facts.
 Given the series 
\begin_inset Formula $\sum a_{n}$
\end_inset

, 
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

1.
 If 
\begin_inset Formula $\sum a_{n}$
\end_inset

 is absolutely convergent and its value is 
\begin_inset Formula $s$
\end_inset

 then any rearrangement of 
\begin_inset Formula $\sum a_{n}$
\end_inset

 will also have a value of 
\begin_inset Formula $s$
\end_inset

.
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

2.
 If 
\begin_inset Formula $\sum a_{n}$
\end_inset

 is conditionally convergent and 
\begin_inset Formula $r$
\end_inset

 is any real number then there is a rearrangement of 
\begin_inset Formula $\sum a_{n}$
\end_inset

 whose value will be 
\begin_inset Formula $r$
\end_inset

.
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Without showing your code, (i.e., what you tried so far), giving proper suggestion to you is not possible

Comment: In the `Local Layout` box, you can add LaTeX commands to customize the appearance of certain environments.

Answer (score 1):

LyX use the styles `amsthm` provides, i.e. `plain`, `definition` and `remark`, so you can modify these styles by adding the following to `Document->Settings->LaTeX Preamble` (for explanation of `\newtheoremstyle` see `amsthm`'s documentation, and for the values I used see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17555/264024))

```
\newtheoremstyle{plain}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\color{red}\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}       

\newtheoremstyle{definition}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\color{red}\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}     

\newtheoremstyle{remark}
  {.5\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {.5\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\color{red}\itshape} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}
```

To change the display in the editor you will need to add to `Document->Settings->Local Layout` for each theorem like environment the following lines (for remark like theorems, the shape is italic and the shape is not bold)

```
ModifyStyle Theorem
LabelFont
Shape               Up
Series              Bold
Color   red
EndFont
End
```

To understand the meaning of this syntax, read section 5.3 of the manual in `Help->Customization`.

Here is your LyX file with the modifications

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass book
\begin_preamble
\newtheoremstyle{plain}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\color{red}\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}       

\newtheoremstyle{definition}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\color{red}\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}     

\newtheoremstyle{remark}
  {.5\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {.5\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\color{red}\itshape} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}       
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
theorems-ams
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\begin_local_layout
Format 66
Requires xcolor

ModifyStyle Theorem
LabelFont
Shape               Up
Series              Bold
Color   red
EndFont
End

ModifyStyle Definition
LabelFont
Shape               Up
Series              Bold
Color   red
EndFont
End

ModifyStyle Fact
LabelFont
Shape               Up
Series              Bold
Color   red
EndFont
End

ModifyStyle Example
LabelFont
Shape               Up
Series              Bold
Color   red
EndFont
End
\end_local_layout
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "Times New Roman"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\float_placement h
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize a4paper
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 2.5cm
\topmargin 2.5cm
\rightmargin 2.5cm
\bottommargin 2.5cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Chapter
series
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
\begin_inset Note Note
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout
10.4
\end_layout

\end_inset

 Convergence & Divergence of Series
\end_layout

\begin_layout Definition
Let 
\begin_inset Formula $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$
\end_inset

 a series, we call the sequence 
\begin_inset Formula $\left\{ s_{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty}$
\end_inset

 the partial sums sequence.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Divergence Test
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Notice that for the two series that converged the series term itself was
 zero in the limit.
 This will always be true for convergent series and leads to the following
 theorem.
 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Theorem
\begin_inset Note Note
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Theorem
\end_layout

\end_inset

 If 
\begin_inset Formula $\sum a_{n}$
\end_inset

 converges then 
\begin_inset Formula $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{\mathrm{n}}=0$
\end_inset

.
 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Fact
Facts.
 Given the series 
\begin_inset Formula $\sum a_{n}$
\end_inset

, 
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

1.
 If 
\begin_inset Formula $\sum a_{n}$
\end_inset

 is absolutely convergent and its value is 
\begin_inset Formula $s$
\end_inset

 then any rearrangement of 
\begin_inset Formula $\sum a_{n}$
\end_inset

 will also have a value of 
\begin_inset Formula $s$
\end_inset

.
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

2.
 If 
\begin_inset Formula $\sum a_{n}$
\end_inset

 is conditionally convergent and 
\begin_inset Formula $r$
\end_inset

 is any real number then there is a rearrangement of 
\begin_inset Formula $\sum a_{n}$
\end_inset

 whose value will be 
\begin_inset Formula $r$
\end_inset

.
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

### LyX's display

[image]

### PDF

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, This is what I want.