# Appropriate parenthesizing of theorem title

Tags: theorems

Is there a way to ensure that we may use `\label{key}[Theoremtitle]` while avoiding getting "[Theoremtitle]" and instead getting "(Theoremtitle)" - as with `[Theoremtitle]\label{key}` in the example below.

Using `[Name]\label{key}` created problems for the line breaking.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{Theorem}[equation]{\em{ T{\footnotesize HEOREM}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}\label{key}[Theoremtitle]
2=2
    \end{Theorem}

\begin{Theorem}[Theoremtitle]\label{key}
    2=2
\end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create the look of small-cap letters? If so, please don't use `T{\footnotesize HEOREM}`; instead, use `\textsc{Theorem}`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What makes you think it's a good idea to write `\begin{Theorem}\label{key}[Theoremtitle]` instead of `\begin{Theorem}[Theoremtitle] \label{key}`? Relatedly, in view of the fact that `\label{...}` doesn't output anything visible, what's the basis for your claim that `\begin{Theorem}[Name]\label{key}` "create[s] problems for the line breaking"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main problem: `\label` *must* go after the *entire* theorem header specification. There is no sensible way to support the syntax you seem to want that doesn't really make sense. Moreover

1. `\em` doesn't take an argument;
2. you don't want `\em` anyway, because the theorem style `remark` already uses `\itshape` for the header;
3. you want *proper* slanted small caps, not the hack with `\footnotesize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fixcmex}% because of lmodern

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{Theorem}[equation]{{\normalfont\scshape\slshape Theorem}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}[Theoremtitle]\label{key}
Something here.
\end{Theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In a better way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fixcmex}% because of lmodern

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17555/4427
\newtheoremstyle{scslheader}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\normalfont} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {\thmname{\textsc{\textsl{#1}}}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{scslheader}
\newtheorem{Theorem}[equation]{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}[Theoremtitle]\label{key}
Something here.
\end{Theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I get the error message Package fixcmex Warning: No change in the math extension font, and do not obtain such changes as you.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal You possibly have an outdated LaTeX distribution.

Comment: I write with Overleaf

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal What version of TeX LIve? Choose 2023.

Comment: Now 2023 chosen. This line  {\thmname{\textsc{\textsl{#1}}}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC creates problems. Is it an abbreviation for possible choices to be made somewhere?

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal It doesn't cause problems to me.

Comment: It may be because my environment persistently causes error for \usepackage{fixcmex}% because of lmodern. I now achieved a good resolution with \newtheorem{Theorem}[equation]{{\large \normalfont\rmfamily\scshape Theorem}} under theorem style Remark. :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your code correctly, you're looking to write "Theorem" with an italic/smallcap lettering combination. The basic Computer Modern/Latin Modern font family doesn't provide such a combination. I suggest you employ the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages, which provide a Times Roman clone. Or, consider employing the `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` packages, which provide a Palatino clone.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{remark} % use upright lettering, no extra vertical whitespace space
\newtheorem{Theorem}[equation]{\textit{\textsc{Theorem}}}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} 
  % Times Roman clone that provides italic-smallcap combination
  
\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}[Theoremtitle] \label{thm:112}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:112}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{Theorem}

\noindent
A cross-reference to Theorem \ref{thm:112}, and another one to equation \eqref{eq:112}.

\end{document}
```