The action of \normalfont and \textit in the theorem heading
I want to write a document with a remark environment, and the caption "Remark" should be Italics, with no bold.
I have tried three ways to declare it in the following example, namely remark, remark1, remark2.
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem*{remark}{\textit{Remark}}
\newtheorem*{remark1}{{\normalfont\textit{Remark 1}}}
\newtheorem*{remark2}{\textit{\normalfont Remark 2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{remark}
    test.
\end{remark}    
    
\begin{remark1}
    test.
\end{remark1}

\begin{remark2}
    test.
\end{remark2}
\end{document}

remark1 is what I want. remark is bold and Italic (which I think I can understand).
remark2 is simply Roman font.
I have two questions:

Is \newtheorem*{remark1}{{\normalfont\textit{Remark 1}}} a recommended way to write an environment with captions Italic but not bold?
Is there some mechanism to explain why \newtheorem*{remark1}{{\normalfont\textit{Remark 1}}} produces a caption in Italic but not bold,
and \newtheorem*{remark2}{\textit{\normalfont Remark 2}} produces a Roman caption?


\normalfont simply resets the font. So \normalfont\textit{} first resets the font, then changes the shape to italic (without changing the series). On the other hand, \textit{\normalfont ...} changes the shape to italic, but then the font gets reset to the default one, thus ignoring everything else.

I believe you would be better off creating a custom style using \newtheoremstyle{<name>}... and then \theoremstyle{<name>}. Have you read Using the amsthm Package? Particularly section 4 Changing styles for theorem-like environments is all about how to style theorem-like environments including custom styles for both body and labels (which is called head in the document).

@campa Thanks. So, is it correct that in LaTeX, the outer command acts first, then the interior, unlike composition functions in maths, say f(g(x)), where inner acts first?

@Celdor Thanks. I will try to read the amsthm package.

Question 1.
No, it's not the recommended way.
Question 2.
In the plain theorem style (that's used by default), the label is boldface (from \bfseries). If you do
{\normalfont\textit{Remark 1}}

you get first normal font, then italic is applied. If you do
\textit{\normalfont Remark 1}

then you essentially get the same as
\bfseries\itshape\normalfont Remark 1

and the last declaration overrides the previous ones.
How to do it.
Use the predefined remark style.
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}
This is an interesting remark
\end{remark}    

\end{document}


I wouldn't inflict readers something like

with long text in italics. Do you see the problem? I see a big one.
Theorems are traditionally typeset in italic font, so they stand out, but the label is also printed in a distinctive style: for amsthm the default is boldface, it could be small caps. The amsthm package provides the plain style for this purpose, but also the definition style that uses the same font for the label, but upright type for the body, and the remark style with label in italics and body in upright type.
With both the label and the body in italics, the reader has no visual clue.
You can define your own style, if you so prefer.
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17555/4427
\newtheoremstyle{asiganremark}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\itshape} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{asiganremark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}
This is an interesting remark
\end{remark}

\end{document}



Thanks, I misread a LaTeX textbook and has not realized remark style is what I want. By the way, could you elaborate on except for too many italics, what are other reasons for not recommending \newtheorem*{remark}{{\normalfont\textit{Remark}}}?

@Asigan The label is “Remark”, not {\normalfont\textit{Remark}}; how to print the label belongs elsewhere.

Sorry, I do not quite catch what that means. Would you please give a concrete example in the answer to elaborate this?

@Asigan it means separation of data and display. You are not suppose to include formatting commands there, only the name of the theorem structure. It is then up to the style in effect at that time to format how Remark should be written in the output. It is the same reason why users should never do \caption{\small foobar}. Reconfigure the look of \caption instead.

Thanks for your patience answering that. But I am still curious what specific error would formatting the style here cause.

@Asigan No TeX error. It's a conceptual error.

Well, this question may be a bit silly, but why we need to avoid such way of declaring, since it is only conceptual wrong, but will not cause actual problems?

@Asigan you don't know if it will cause problem. You implicitly assume that the argument is used only in one place, the one where you want the font. But what if some style or extension package makes use of it in some other place, e.g. to write a list of theorems, or to add something to the bookmarks, or for some fancy cross referencing?

@UlrikeFischer Yes, I neglected that. Thanks for your comment!
