Style for theorem and definition environments
In the following code, I need Theorem to be in bold and the body of definition not to be in italic. Is there a way to realize this?
Thank you!
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref, cleveref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{verbatim,enumitem}

\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@thm
{\let\thm@indent\indent}{\let\thm@indent\noindent}%
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \title{Result}
\chapter{First}
\section{background concept}

\begin{theorem}\label{key}
    Theorem 1 says...
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}\label{key}
    Definition 1 says ...
\end{definition}
\subsection{brain and its function}
\subsection{differen techniques in barain stimulation}
\subsubsection{DBS}
\subsubsection{TMS}
\chapter{Second}
\section{background concept}
\subsection{brain and its function}
\subsection{differen techniques in barain stimulation}
\subsubsection{DBS}
\subsubsection{TMS}

\end{document}

Edit
It works now for definition thanks to @egreg comment. Could you please help for Theorem? it is still not bold as you can see in the screenshot


Move \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition} after \theoremstyle{definition}.

Thanks @egreg, I am still having an issue with Theorem not being bold

Indeed, amsboox uses small caps.

Oh, what should I use to stay close to the style of a thesis?

Move definition after \theoremstyle{definition}.
You also seem to want a different theorem style than the one provided by amsbook. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17555/4427 for the parameters.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage[british]{babel} % better at the beginning

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
%\usepackage{txfonts} % avoid it
\usepackage{newtx} % better than txfonts
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{verbatim,enumitem}

%\usepackage{chngcntr} % no longer needed
\usepackage{hyperref, cleveref} % should be last

\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\newtheoremstyle{realplain}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{realplain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\begin{document}
    
    \title{Result}
\chapter{First}
\section{background concept}

\begin{theorem}\label{key}
    Theorem 1 says...
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}\label{key}
    Definition 1 says ...
\end{definition}
\subsection{brain and its function}
\subsection{differen techniques in barain stimulation}
\subsubsection{DBS}
\subsubsection{TMS}
\chapter{Second}
\section{background concept}
\subsection{brain and its function}
\subsection{differen techniques in barain stimulation}
\subsubsection{DBS}
\subsubsection{TMS}

\end{document}


Look at the changes and comments in the preamble.

Great comments and answer! Thank you!
